# Word 2010: Mail merge to a table in a schema other than dbo

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to perform a mail merge to a SQL Server 2005 view.  I created the same view twice, once without specifying the schema (ie. DBO), and once with specifying the schema. In SQL Server Management Studio, logged in using Windows authentication, I have no problem accessing both views.

Using the "Select Recipients" > "Use Existing List" option in Word 2012, I made a connection to the database server using Windows authentication.  Both views are included in the list of available tables, as shown below.

[image: Select database and table]

Following through, I created a connection for each view.  I am able to successfully merge from the view owned by "dbo".  I cannot however merge from the view owned by "Permit".  I receive the following error.

[image: Error message]

The only difference that I know of is that the successful one uses the default "dbo" schema, while the other uses "Permit".  Is there an extra step to ensure the schema information is used when merging?  How do I do a mail merge off a table or view not owned by "dbo"?

**Update**

I did some additional testing.  Looking at the ODC file used to define the connection, I see that the schema information is properly recorded.

[image: ODC File]

For testing, I renamed the ODC file to an HTM file, and opened it in Internet Explorer.  It displayed the live data from the database without an issue.

I then tried doing the mail merge while listening with SQL Server Profiler, just to see what queries Word was trying to run.

[image: SQL Server Profiler]

As I suspected, Word 2010 is not using the schema information when mail merging.

Comment: I tried manually changing the `<meta name=Table content=CirculationForComment>` to include the schema name. `<meta name=Table content=Permit.CirculationForComment>` does not work because the mail merge code automatically puts double-quotes around the table name.

Comment: I'm leaning toward this being a bug in the way Word 2010 does mail merging.  I'm posted the question to the Microsoft Community form as well ( http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-mail-merge-to-a-table-in-a-schema-other/e478f3ae-18fe-446b-9f7a-01060205f2d8 ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem in Word 2003, Word 2007, and Word 2010.  There is a Microsoft knowledge base article that contains the answer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918295

The article describes the process for Word 2003 and Word 2007, but Word 2010 is similar.  Here's what I did for Word 2010.

1. Exit all Office programs.
2. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedit**, and then click **OK**.
3. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common**
4. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD Value**.
5. Type **UseQualifiedTableNameForMailMerge**, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
6. Right-click **UseQualifiedTableNameForMailMerge**, and then click **Modify**.
7. In the **Value** data box, type **1**, and then click **OK**.
8. On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.